How do the various churches define the moment we receive the Holy Spirit?"
I am look for more insight. I have seen many interpretation of scripture but not one that completely explains what my question is.

you might want to narrow/specify it to a denomination?

Alternatively, "How do the various churches define the moment we receive the Holy Spirit?" would allow for each denomination to respond. I responded based on AJL777's interest in Eastern Orthodoxy and Old Catholic churches in the previous question.

Seams that im not well versed on direct questions .

According to the Eastern Orthodox Church a christian receives the Holy Spirit during the sacrament of Chrismation. (Anointing)
The sacrament of Chrismation is immediately after the sacrament of Baptism. (Or by itself through "oikonomia" like my own experience because I was properly baptised in a different Church before converting.)
These sacraments are given regardless of age. (No age of reason limitation to the mysteries of God's grace, we do not understand them)

The sacrament of Chrismation is an extension of Pentecost, the day when the Holy Spirit was poured out on the Apostles. Through this Mystery (Sacrament) an individual becomes a layperson (Laos), the people of God.

Through Chrismation every member of the Church becomes a prophet, and receives a share in the royal priesthood of Christ; all Christians alike, because they are chrismated, are called to act as conscious witnesses to the Truth. - Bishop Kallistos Ware

The scripture basis for this is immediately quoted by Bishop Ware

You have an anointing (chrisma) from the Holy One, and know all things (1 John 2:20)

Another Biblical basis for this is found in St. Peter's quotes of the prophecy of Joel "I will pour out my spirit on all flesh" (Acts 2:17, Joel 2:28). Other old testament prophets also mention this promise (Jeremiah 31:31-34) and (Ezekiel 36:25-27)
This is an amazing promise, because in the old testament only the select few received this gift of anointment. (Usually Kings, Judges or Prophets).

I will stop there, as you did not ask for a historical totality of verses related to the Holy Spirit. (Acts 1:5, John 7:37-39 & 14:16 & 16:13-14...)

The more information I get the more I understand. This platform is for sure a blessing for many people. I have been asking many questions for years and no one but an AI will answer them with facts.

@AJL777 This site will give you facts, and some people who answer will even attempt to provide sources for their facts. Be it biblical, church fathers, or church tradition (Easter Orthodox Church uses all of these).
